# Multipeer Connectivity Framework - Disconnected peers stay in session in MCBrowserController

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, session, multipeer-connectivity

There is a similar question to this here:[Multipeer Connectivity Framework - Lost Peer stays in Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23014523/multipeer-connectivity-framework-lost-peer-stays-in-session)

But the answers have unfortunately not helped, or I have misunderstood them.

I have my multipeer connectivity app, and have also tested Apples own MultipeerGroupChat app.

When a peer disconnects, sometimes they stay in the session. This results in failed connections when the peer tries to reconnect.

I have tried [session disconnect] in applicationWillTerminate, but it still occurs.

How can I have the MCBrowserViewController update itself with who is connected and who isn't?

```
-(id)init{
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    _peerID = nil;
    _session = nil;
    _browser = nil;
    _advertiser = nil;
}
    _appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    return self;
}

-(void)setupMCBrowser{
_browser = [[MCBrowserViewController alloc] initWithServiceType:@"session" session:_session];
_browser.maximumNumberOfPeers = 8;
}

-(void)session:(MCSession *)session peer:(MCPeerID *)peerID didChangeState:(MCSessionState)state{
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"peerID": peerID,
                       @"state" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:state]
                       };

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MCDidChangeStateNotification"
                                                    object:nil
                                                  userInfo:dict];

switch (state)
{

    case MCSessionStateConnecting:
    {

        _statusID = @"Connecting";
        break;
    }

    case MCSessionStateConnected:
    {

        _statusID = @"Connected";
        if (_firstPeer == NULL){
            _firstPeer = peerID.displayName;
        }
        else if (_secondPeer == NULL){
            _secondPeer = peerID.displayName;
        }
        else if (_thirdPeer == NULL){
            _thirdPeer = peerID.displayName;
        }
        break;
    }

    case MCSessionStateNotConnected:
    {
        if ([peerID isEqual:_firstPeer]){
            _firstPeer = NULL;
        }
        else if ([peerID isEqual:_secondPeer]){
            _secondPeer = NULL;
        }
        else if ([peerID isEqual:_thirdPeer]){
            _thirdPeer = NULL;
        }
        _statusID = @"Connection Lost";
        break;
    }
}


}
```