# MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser delegate methods never called

Tags: multipeer-connectivity, mcsession

Implementing an app with automatic connection between devices to exchange small bunch of data, using Multi-peer Connectivity framework and Nearby Services (both browser and advertiser).

I built a Session Manager handling all connections details. Its delegate is a View Controller in order to handle updates of UI when data are received.

The Session Manager builds:

- A Service Advertiser, the delegate being the Session Manager
- A Service Browser, the delegate being also the Session Manager

Launching the app on two devices (one under Xcode to get the logs, the other one stand alone), I receive a Found Peer message through Service Browser delegate corresponding method.

As stated in another message, I compare the displayName property of MCPeerID (both local and from received Peer) to decide whichever of both will send invitation, thus avoiding cross-invitations.

As stated on another message [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264319/ios-multipeer-connectivity-framework-invitationhandler-doesnt-seem-to-accept), I have also added the "optional" MCSession delegate method `- (void)session:didReceiveCertificate:fromPeer:certificateHandler:`

However, delegate method `(void)advertiser:didReceiveInvitationFromPeer:withContext:invitationHandler:` of MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser is never called. There is only a NotConnected message received by the MCSession delegate method `(void)session:peer:didChangeState:`after the timeout setup in the `invitePeer:toSession:withContext:timeout:`method.

In the various options proposed:

- Session is initialized with security nil and MCEncryptionNone;
- discoveryInfo are nil;
- context sent in the invitation is just a short string archived as NSData.

To troubleshoot:

- I have checked that all items were existing (session and its delegate, advertiser and its delegate).
- Service Browser and Advertiser are never stopped, as long as app is active.

I don't know where to look  over now!

Comment: Are the machine running Xcode and the device on the same WiFi network?

Comment: Are you perhaps initializing the MCSession with the peer you get in the browser:foundPeer:withDiscoveryInfo: message rather than the local peer in your browser?  I made that mistake...

Comment: I am interested in this issue as well. My delegate methods for multi peer are not getting called.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the MCpeerID you use for your local peer is the same for both the discovery and invitation phases.

I had a structure with a separate session manager to the connect/transfer worker. I made the mistake of initialising a new MCpeerID in the worker to create a session prior to the invitation, resulting in the same behaviour.

Passing the MCpeerID and MCNearbyServiceBrowser to the worker to create the session and invite fixed the issue.