# Multipeer Connectivity : Not discovering device over Wifi Infrastructure

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, multipeer-connectivity

I created a network on my Macbook Pro (Right below the list of WiFi's) and I had 2 iOS 7 (iPad 2 & iPod Touch) devices join to this network. When I started to browse for devices, I just have the "Searching " and the wheel spinning in the native BrowseViewController. Apparently one device is not discovering the other device. But the setup works when I have bluetooth switched ON on both. Please, can you help me with this ?

Comment: Please clarify. Mac is broadcasting an endpoint, the two ios devices are searching for it. If mac uses Bluetooth ok? Please say exactly what config works and what does not.

Comment: chat me @mrsamkitjain@gmail.com..if you have more issues about multipeer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found out the issue. In fact, an observation here. It is not working only on the iPad 2 I am using. I tried the same code with 2 iPods, the result : ButterSmooth.
But what hurts is the fact that nowhere its mentioned. Note, my iPad 2 is running iOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

I'm actively developing MPC at the moment and debugging using two Macs.  As @samkit mentions, the devices need to be on the same WiFi network.  If that is true for you, make sure you also implement the didReceiveCertificate method per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935288/why-does-my-mcsession-peer-disconnect-randomly) to ensure your devices get to the connected state

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Both devices are connected to same wifi. They will definitely work.